# `systemctl status atop` shows it has failed, but there is no error message

Tags: systemd, logs, atop

I installed `atop`, and then immediately upgraded from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30.

Now `atop` failed to start during boot.  But there is no error message.  It only shows that `atop` exited with code 7.  Why do I not see an error message?

```
$ rpm -q atop
atop-2.4.0-1.fc30.x86_64
$ journalctl -u atop
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-02-28 17:23:24 GMT, end at Tue 2019-04-30 22:41:24 BST. --
Apr 30 17:27:05 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
Apr 30 18:34:31 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: Stopping Atop advanced performance monitor...
Apr 30 18:34:34 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: Stopped Atop advanced performance monitor.
-- Reboot --
Apr 30 19:48:56 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
Apr 30 19:48:58 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: atop.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
Apr 30 19:48:58 fedora29-vm systemd[1]: atop.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atop` uses the log file `/var/log/atop/daily.log`

```
$ cd /var/log/atop/
$ ls
atop_20190430  daily.log

$ cat /var/log/atop/daily.log 
existing file /var/log/atop/atop_20190430 has incompatible header

$ sudo rm atop_20190430

$ sudo systemctl start atop
$ sudo systemctl status atop
● atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-04-30 22:36:21 BST; 5s ago
     Docs: man:atop(1)
 Main PID: 11429 (atop)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2890)
   Memory: 5.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─11429 /usr/bin/atop -R -w /var/log/atop/atop_20190430 600

Apr 30 22:36:21 fedora30-vm systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
```

---

On Debian Linux, you may notice some `atop` package updates have a related changelog entry, shown below :-).

> atop sometimes changes the format of the raw log files. In that case, atop
>     -r will not be able to read the files written by previous version. The
>     atopconvert(1) tool can be locally used to convert the old log files.
>
> In postinst, the package checks whether the new atop binary will read the
>     latest raw file and try to convert the file. All other files in /var/log/atop
>     are left unchanged.